# Dont allow the user to add the existing record in the table

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

When i select the item from dropdown and it will add to the table if the user will add it again it should show error that item is already added.

```
<select id="dropdownUsers"></select>
<table border="1" id="tableshow">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>ID</td>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>unit Price</td>
                <td>qunatity</td>
                <td>total</td>
                <td>Actions</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    <tbody id="tabledata"></tbody>
    </table>
```

ajax call to bind the dropdown

```
              $.ajax({
                     url: "/home/fillDropdown",
                     type: "Get",
                     success: function (data) {

                         for (var i = 0; i < data.listUsers.length; i++) {
                             var opt = new Option(data.listUsers[i].strFirstName, data.listUsers[i].iUserInfoId);
                             $('#dropdownUsers').append(opt);

                         }

                     }

                 });
```

ajax call to bind table

```
            $('#buttonAllocateRoom1').on('click', function (e) {

                     $("#tableshow").show();
```

This will fetch the row of td from the table it will return the list of array of id

---

```
                     $('#tableshow > tbody  > tr ').each(function (index, td) {
                         arr = $(this).find('td');
                         arrlist[index] = arr[0].innerHTML;
                         index++;
                     });
```

---

```
                     if (arrlist.length > 0) {

                         for (var k = 0; k <= arrlist.length - 1; k++) {

                 //Then the i had compared the array with dropdownlist

                             if (arrlist[k] !== $("#dropdownUsers").val()) {
                                 var val = $("#dropdownUsers").val();
                                 $.ajax({
                                     dataType: 'json',
                                     type: 'POST',
                                     contentType: "application/Json; charset=utf-8",
                                     url: '/Home/fillDropdownbyids',
                                     data: JSON.stringify({ id: val }),
                                     success: function (response) {
                                         $("#id").append(response.user.iUserInfoId + " ")
                                         var tr = '';


                                         tr += '<tr class="row"><td class="rowid' + val + '">' + response.user.iUserInfoId + '</td><td>' + response.user.strFirstName + '</td><td><input type="text" id="unittextbox' + val + '"></td><td><input type="text" id="quantextbox' + val + '" onfocusout="get(' + val + ')"></td><td><input type="text" id="totaltextbox' + val + '" ></td><td><input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)"></td></tr>';


                                         $('#tabledata').append(tr);
                                     },
                                 });
                             }
                             else {
                                 alert("already exists")
                                 return;
                             }
                         }
                     }
```

*** For First Time Adding the item to table ****

```
                     else if (arrlist.length == 0)
                     {
                         var val = $("#dropdownUsers").val();
                         $.ajax({
                             dataType: 'json',
                             type: 'POST',
                             contentType: "application/Json; charset=utf-8",
                             url: '/Home/fillDropdownbyids',
                             data: JSON.stringify({ id: val }),
                             success: function (response) {
                                 $("#id").append(response.user.iUserInfoId + " ")
                                 var tr = '';


                                 tr += '<tr class="row"><td class="rowid' + val + '">' + response.user.iUserInfoId + '</td><td>' + response.user.strFirstName + '</td><td><input type="text" id="unittextbox' + val + '"></td><td><input type="text" id="quantextbox' + val + '" onfocusout="get(' + val + ')"></td><td><input type="text" id="totaltextbox' + val + '" ></td><td><input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)"></td></tr>';


                                 $('#tabledata').append(tr);
                             },
                         });

                     }
                     });
```

Comment: Can you try to remove that item from the dropdown once it is added in the table? If you don't want duplicates, just remove it after adding it to table.

Comment: i can do that but i m also allowing the user to delete the row if it is added by mistake then i have to add that item to dropdown again at the time of deleting the item from the table.

Comment: I would suggest to make a global array of the Row IDs that are in the table and check the existence of them into the drop down. You might need to create a unique identifier for each record. Check with $.inArray(value, array) method of jQuery.

Comment: verification of duplicate rows should be done on the server side, and the ajax call would return an error if a duplicate insert attempt was encountered. Attempting to verify this on the client is unsafe because JavaScript can be bypassed easily by malicious users. You _could_ try and detect duplicates before the ajax happens just to enhance the user experience, but you still _must_ check again on the server if you value the integrity of your data.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $('#buttonAllocateRoom1').on('click', function (e) {
        $("#tableshow").show();
        var val = $("#dropdownUsers").val();
        $.ajax({
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: "application/Json; charset=utf-8",
            url: '/Home/fillDropdownbyids',
            data: JSON.stringify({ id: val }),
            success: function (response) {

                var arr = [];
                var arrlist = [];
                var index = 0;
                $('#tableshow > tbody  > tr ').each(function (index, td) {
                    arr = $(this).find('td');
                    arrlist[index] = arr[0].innerHTML;

                });
                index++;
                alert(arrlist)

                if (arrlist.length == 0) {
                    var tr = '';
                    tr += '<tr class="row"><td class="rowid' + val + '">' + response.user.iUserInfoId + '</td><td>' + response.user.strFirstName + '</td><td><input type="text" id="unittextbox' + val + '"></td><td><input type="text" id="quantextbox' + val + '" onfocusout="get(' + val + ')"></td><td><input type="text" id="totaltextbox' + val + '" ></td><td><input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)"></td></tr>';
                    $('#tabledata').append(tr);
                }
                else {
                    if ($.inArray(val, arrlist) == -1) {
                        $("#id").append(response.user.iUserInfoId + " ")
                        var tr = '';
                        tr += '<tr class="row"><td class="rowid' + val + '">' + response.user.iUserInfoId + '</td><td>' + response.user.strFirstName + '</td><td><input type="text" id="unittextbox' + val + '"></td><td><input type="text" id="quantextbox' + val + '" onfocusout="get(' + val + ')"></td><td><input type="text" id="totaltextbox' + val + '" ></td><td><input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)"></td></tr>';
                        $('#tabledata').append(tr);
                    }
                    else {
                        alert("Alreadt Exits");
                    }
                }
            }


        })





        });
```